# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle$ a field of order 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know that the ideal $\langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle$ is maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. (I have proved this by assuming an strictly bigger ideal and showing this to be the whole ring..!!). Therefore, $F=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle$ is a field.

$\rangle$ But, now I'm suspecting that $F$ is a field of $4$ elements.

The reason behind this seems so intuitive but even I don't know whether I am doing any mistake...I include the my intuition behind this:

Any element, say, $~f(x)+ \langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle~\in F$ can be written in the form $(ax+b)+\langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ (using Division Algorithm). Now reducing $a,b$ by $\mod 2$ we see that there are $4$ choices of $a,b$.

In another direction, I am suspecting the following isomorphism:

> $F=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle~ \cong ~\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle~\cong~\mathbb{F}_4 \dots\dots\dots(1)$

The last isomorphism of (1) is easy. I try to prove the 1st isomorphism appears in (1) by defining the epimorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[x] \to\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ by $$f(x)\mapsto \overline{f}(x)+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$$

Where the $~\overline{f}$ denotes the image of $~f$ under canonical epimorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

$\rangle$ But I am unable to proof that, $\ker\phi=\langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle$

Please help me to show the last equality...!!If I made any mistake, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\phi(x^2+x+1)=\phi(2)=0$ and hence $\supset$ holds.

For the other implication Let $\phi(f)=0$.

By long division
$$f(x)=q(x)(x^2+x+1)+ax+b$$ 
and hence 
$$0=\phi(f)=\overline{ax+b}$$

Deduce from here that $ax+b \in <2>$.

Comment: Okay,...if both of a and b is even or both of them is odd then there is nothing to prove...if  one of $a$ and $b$ is odd and other is even say, $b$ is odd then $[a]x+[b] \in <x^2+x+1>$ in $\mathbb{z}_2[x]$ implies $1 \in <x^2+x+1>$ and which contradicts the maximality of $<x^2+x+1>$ in $\mathbb{z}_2[x]$. Also if $a$ is odd and $b$ is even then we have $<x> \subset <x^2+x+1>$ which is not also possible since $<x>$ is maximal in $\mathbb{z}_2[x]$....Am I right?

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh You try to prove that both are even. Note that $\phi(ax+b)=0$ means that $aX+b=0$ in $\mathbb Z_2[X]/<1+x+x^2>$. Now use the fact that $\mathbb Z_2[X]/<1+x+x^2>$ is a field with 4 elements.

Comment: Oho...I think I got your point :...$\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/<x^2+x+1>=\{cx+d+<x^2+x+1>~|~c,d \in \mathbb{Z}_2\}$...So here $\phi(ax+b)=0$ imply $a,b$ are both even...