# Is division algorithm true in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a confusion about one of my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748866/is-mathbbzx-langle-x2x1-2-rangle-a-field-of-order-4) I once asked on this site:
In this question I wrote this followings:

> Any element, say, $~f(x)+ \langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle~\in F$ can be written in the form $(ax+b)+\langle x^2+x+1, 2\rangle$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ (using Division Algorithm). Now reducing $a,b$ by $\mod 2$ we see that there are $4$ choices of $a,b$.

But is this idea really true? I mean, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a Euclidean Domain. So I think the Division Algorithm is not applicable there! Am I right? Please mention if there is some silly mistake. Thank you.

Comment: The division algorithm works over any commutative ring **provided** one is dividing by a **monic** polynomial.

Comment: How to prove this...or any theorem suggesting it..

Comment: How could you long divide $x^4+2x^3-17x+11$ by $x^2-2x+4$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: @Randall $x^4+2x^3-17x+11=(x^2-2x+4)(x^2+4x+4)-25x-5$.

Comment: Well, dang.....

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh "how to prove this" Exactly in the same way you prove it for division when the ring is a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R$ be any ring, $g\in R[x]$ monic of degree $m$. 
Suppose $f$ has degree $n\ge m$ and its leading coefficient is $a_n$. 
Then $f_1:=f(x) -a_ng(x)x^{n-m}$ is in the same $g$-coset as $f$ and has strictly smaller degree. Iterate it until the degree becomes smaller than $m$.